# Wordpress: Custom profile form not working in Ultimate member plugin

Tags: wordpress

When I create a custom form for a custom user role using ultimate member plugin, it doesn't work. Only the default profile form works. Please what can be the problem. I need to create different profile forms for different types of users

Comment: Ask first the plugin support. As Stack Overflow is mainly about programming, you won't get much help unless you post error message or source code (that may be forbidden for a commercial plugin).

Comment: Oh okay, thank you

Comment: @ifeoluwaking So, is there a solution for this one?

Answer (score 3):

The cause of this issue is that the original User page only contains the shortcode for the default profile form.

After you create all of your custom profile forms, and assign the relevant roles to each (Form Settings -> Disable Global Settings -> Select Role), **you need to add the short codes of all your forms to the User page**, just one after another.

UltimateMember will decide which of the forms to display depending on the user's role.

Comment: I did not know that. Thanks, I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

So on the view user page, add the shortcode for the custom form, in addition to the existing default profile form.

It's a bit weird to have multiple shortcodes but it will only show the one for that role.

Also make sure to assign a the Custom Role to the Custom Form, as stated by Michael Rodriguez